# How to generate Google presentation slides with Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to generate slides using data I have in a Google Spreadsheet. I already use Google App Scripts for the spreadsheet and they are very handy. I can't however find a way to generate pages with a background image and export it as a PDF file.

This would be very appreciated because I have to generate ~1000 pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't supported at this time. Refer to Open [Issue 1573](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1573). Star it to add your vote and receive updates.

Comment: As of today presentations are still not scriptable.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Google released a Slide API in Google API Section today:

https://developers.google.com/slides/

Now you can use some server code (Java, php, [...] ) using Google services (Google App Engine e.g.) that create/manage Google Slides and then call it with Requests in Google App Script.

Ps: But still not available natively for Google App Script.

Answer (score 1):

See [this example answer which shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662455/how-to-download-google-slides-as-images/40678925#40678925) a simple request as part of another solution within Apps Script. Combined with the [REST reference](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/) it should be possible to do whatever you want.