# How to download Google Slides as images?

Tags: google-apps-script, png, google-slides

I am a big fan of using Google Slides as a cloud-hosted lightweight illustrator replacement (that also happens to be collaborative and free!). I wrote up a few thoughts on my process here:

https://medium.com/@tomcritchlow/how-to-use-google-slides-as-a-free-cloud-hosted-illustrator-replacement-f472e6c3a881

What I'm trying to do in my workflow is download all of the slides in a presentation as images at once? The Google Slides UI only lets you download each slide as a PNG one at a time?

Is this possible using add-ons or Apps Scripts somehow? Not sure where to start... Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the tip in the post that slide size can be adjusted to be pixel-based. Not sure if the approach I suggest below could be enhanced with that solution to require lower DPI.

Answer (score 19):

The following worked for me:

#### Set up

Under **Resources > Developer Console Project > View Developers Console**, enable both the **Slides API** and the **Drive API**.

#### Execution

Replace the ID taken from the Slides URL in the `start()` function, and run it, e.g.:

```
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/<id>/edit
```

and the function will save the PNGs to your Drive. This could be extended to group them all in a specific folder etc.

```
function downloadPresentation(id) {
  var slideIds = getSlideIds(id); 

  for (var i = 0, slideId; slideId = slideIds[i]; i++) {
    downloadSlide('Slide ' + (i + 1), id, slideId);
  }
}

function downloadSlide(name, presentationId, slideId) {
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/' + presentationId +
    '/export/png?id=' + presentationId + '&pageid=' + slideId; 
  var options = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var image = response.getAs(MimeType.PNG);
  image.setName(name);
  DriveApp.createFile(image);
}

function getSlideIds(presentationId) {
  var url = 'https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations/' + presentationId;
  var options = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  var slideData = JSON.parse(response);
  return slideData.slides.map(function(slide) {
    return slide.objectId;
  });
}

function start() {
  downloadPresentation('Slides document id')
}
```

Comment: Works, thank you. Note for those new to Google Apps Script, you should open the Slides presentation > Tools > Script editor > Copy-paste the above code into Code.gs. Then, follow @Bardy's steps above to enable Slides and Drive APIs for this specific Slides document. Finally, run the code. Files will be saved in your Drive root folder

Comment: Honestly, it took a little while to figure out but this worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to get slide images is to use the `presentations.pages.getThumbnail` endpoint:

https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/getThumbnail

The following Apps Script code uses `SlidesApp` to iterate over the slides, the Slides Advanced Service to generate the thumbnail image, `UrlFetchApp` to fetch the generated thumbnail, and `DriveApp` to save it to Drive:

```
function exportSlideImages(presentationId) {
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId);
  presentation.getSlides().forEach(function(slide, i) {
    // slide = presentation.getSlides()[];
    var thumbnail = Slides.Presentations.Pages.getThumbnail(presentationId, slide.getObjectId(), {
      'thumbnailProperties.thumbnailSize': 'LARGE'
    });
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(thumbnail.contentUrl);
    var blob = response.getBlob();
    blob.setName('slide' + (i + 1) + '.png');
    var file = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
    Logger.log('Created file "%s" for slide number %s', file.getName(), i + 1);
  });
}
```

Comment: This API required Authorization. I want to get thumbnail image of public slide. Is there a way to get preview thumbnail without Authorization?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with a slightly lower-tech way. This does have artifacts from compression that comes with the PDF export, but gets close enough to original quality for me.

I added annotations to images in Google Slides, to use the images in marvelapp.com eventually. So I exported Google slides as PDF.

Then issued command line (requires ghostscript to be installed). I actually needed to do 1200 DPI here. This is to get the level of detail I had in the original images, which I had dropped to google slides.

```
gs -sDEVICE=pngalpha -o file-%03d.png -r1200 demo.pdf
```

As my slides were made up of pictures I'd just dragged to google slides, I issued the following to crop white areas connected to image borders (requires ImageMagick installed)

```
mogrify -trim *.png
```

Finally, I resize the images back to the original size of images. Sharpen level of 0.5 does not seem to cause significant artifacts, 1.0 was too strong.

```
convert -resize 1794x971 -sharpen 0x0.5 *.png
```

You could probably combine these into a single operation. For some reason, the actual conversion process in such high DPI was a lot faster for me directly through gs than using ImageMagick.

Comment: +1 this answer

I just used ImageMagick as described here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45862/save-all-google-presentation-slides-as-images/92034#92034?newreg=4f0aadc1a03e4e5c9a9a71004e169dc7

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else out there looking for an answer, I just found the official export URL from my JavaScript console, when clicking the "Download -> JPG" from under the file menu, the URL I saw in the console which downloads the picture is (For example):
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1xRtKNtBaaiGzZx3sUz2k3OUdW0hbPmm8HsRVz222SnA/export/jpeg?id=1xRtKNtBaaiGzZx3sUz2k3OUdW0hbPmm8HsRVz222SnA&pageid=g6eb73d655b_0_0

Which is really:

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/YourPublicSlideshowID/export/jpeg?id=YourPublicSlideshowID&pageid=TheSlideID

"TheSlideID" can be found by doing the following: Go to your Google Slide show file, go to a different slide than the first one, then copy the URL, it should be like:

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1xRtKNtBaaiGzZx3sUz2k3OUdW0hbPmm8HsRVz222SnA/edit#slide=id.g6eb73d655b_0_0

for example. Notice, after the "edit" keyword, is "#slide=id.g6eb73d655b_0_0", to extract the SlideId (to plug in to the other URL) is very simple: just replace the text "#slide=id." with "" (if you're doing it programmatically, or just manually), then plug in the remainder (in this case "g6eb73d655b_0_0") to "TheSlideID" in the above URL, and vwala!

Answer (score 0):

This bookmark snippet from https://aijayvishnu.medium.com/how-to-download-google-slide-presentations-published-to-the-web-3c1564bd92c1 will put all slides on one page.
It's really easy to use, create a bookmark and click it. (More info in the article)

```js
javascript: 
var atag = "punch-viewer-content",
    btag = "-caption",
    ctag = "aria-setsize",
    dtag = "aria-posinset",
    msvg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg"),
    node = document.querySelectorAll('[class$="' + btag + '"]')[0],
    view = document.getElementsByClassName(atag)[0],
    size = node.getAttribute(ctag),
    data = "", 
    func = () => { 
      data += msvg[0].outerHTML;
      if((i = node.getAttribute(dtag))==size) document.write(data); 
      else view.click(), setTimeout(func,10) 
    };func()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have searched few places, found some answers for downloading google slides as image but they seem complicated or takes more time than I expect.

I want to get all the slides of a google slide presentation as png or jpg file and then save them in a google drive. Actually I want them in my local computer. But I though If I can do this, then later I will download and use.

So how to do it quickly and easily?
I found this [link](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1ZXT1YemGiNcFxiN61hwew_SEsEDC4cl_V-j0V_hkj6w/copy). But no easy answer here.

**Advantage of using this script to convert google slides into images :**
If you like to download them into your PC, you can download the folder. If you like to share a single image to others you can do that as well.
Most importantly, if you want to share presentation as image file- just share the folder.

Here is [my Google Slide](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1ZXT1YemGiNcFxiN61hwew_SEsEDC4cl_V-j0V_hkj6w/copy). You can copy it. Open  the apps script from Tool>Script Editor. Then run "generateScreenshots" function. This function is not a work of myself, but got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59845753/google-suite-apps-script-download-slides-as-png-files-via-api). Only modified to save images into a specific folder name "Test_Image". You can create your own folder in google drive and then use folder ID in the apps script and update this line:

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Folder ID");//Replace Folder ID with your own folder
```

Complete code is here.

```js
function generateScreenshots() {
  // open Google Slide and then copy Google Slide ID (presentation ID)
  var presentationId ="1ZXT1YemGiNcFxiN61hwew_SEsEDC4cl_V-j0V_hkj6w";
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId);
  var baseUrl =
    "https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations/{presentationId}/pages/{pageObjectId}/thumbnail";
  var parameters = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
    contentType: "application/json",
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  // Log URL of the main thumbnail of the deck
  Logger.log(Drive.Files.get(presentationId).thumbnailLink);

  // For storing the screenshot image URLs
  var screenshots = [];

  var slides = presentation.getSlides().forEach(function(slide, index) {
    var url = baseUrl
      .replace("{presentationId}", presentationId)
      .replace("{pageObjectId}", slide.getObjectId());
    var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, parameters));

    // Upload Googel Slide image to a  Google Drive Folder
    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(response.contentUrl).getBlob();
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Your Folder ID");//Replace Folder ID with your own folder
    folder.createFile(blob).setName("Image " + (index + 1) + ".png");

    screenshots.push(response.contentUrl);
  });

  return screenshots;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have made https://github.com/Nashev/CreatePNGSequenceForSlides plugin to call https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/getThumbnail for each slide with little GUI

It can be used with a huge presentation, to overcome Google limits for script executing time and a "getThumbnail" call count.

[image]