# Support for Google Slides

Tags: google-apps-script

Are there any plans for supporting apps script in google slides?
I wanted to code a progress bar to.. well show the progress of my presentation but as it turns out, slides does not support apps script.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to regularly check [Google Apps Script - Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/) to be updated on the major changes in each release of Google Apps Script. This is intended to help developers identify recent changes in behavior.

However, you may want to also check features that you can use to show progress bar with the use of [Google Slides API](https://developers.google.com/slides/). Many of the features that make Google Slides so successful are available through the API. This lets you access and update presentations programatically, integrating data from various sources and producing finished presentations in a fraction of the time.

I haven't actually tried using this API, but this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367365/403-error-with-message-google-slides-api-has-not-been-used-in-project-befor/41370122#41370122) shows how you can use the [apps-script-oauth2](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2) library to generate your OAuth token and be able to use Google Slides API.

For missing features that you might need or like, you may file requests [here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?labels=Type-Enhancement,API-Slides).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sure this may help me :) - I'll look into these links and check if there's a solution.