# Save a range of Google Sheet as image in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I need to save a specifit range or a Google Sheet as image (PNG, JPG...) on a folder in Google Drive.

Comment: In your situation, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/63471232

Comment: Thanks, but in this example, just copy the text of the range, not the formats, colors, size, etc...

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes. In the current stage, unfortunately, when `Charts.newTableChart()` is used, only the texts are used without including the colors and font information. It seems that this is the current specification. I apologize for this. If you want to include the colors, font, and so on, for example, how about converting the Spreadsheet to PDF? If you want to convert PDF to image, this thread might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/65960525 If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: I'm going to try it, thanks!