# Google Sheet Range mail pdf

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am all new for the google app script, don't know whether it is possible or not.
Need a script to send the defined range(A1:I5) as PDF on email (email address defined in K2,cc and bcc as defined in script).

SS link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tmnDOMyupjeO8d65qHQsxb5KrrKeq7pMYIE8h2VmEJ4/edit#gid=0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to export the range of "A1:I5" in "Sheet1" as a PDF file, and retrieve the email address from cell "K2". And, you want to send them as an email.
- You want to declare `cc` and `bcc` in the script.

When [this information](https://gist.github.com/Spencer-Easton/78f9867a691e549c9c70) is used, the endpoint for exporting the range of "A1:I5" in "Sheet1" as a PDF data is like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/export?format=pdf&range=A1:I5&gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}`. When this endpoint is used, the sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const cc = ""; // Please set cc.
  const bcc = ""; // Please set bcc.

  // Retrieve Spreadsheet and Sheet objects.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  // Retrieve PDF blob.
  const url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/export?format=pdf&range=A1:I5&gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}`;
  const pdfBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob();

  // Send an email using email from cell "K2".
  const email = sheet.getRange("k2").getValue();
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: email,
    cc: cc || null,
    bcc: bcc || null,
    subject: "sample subject",
    body: "sample body",
    attachments: [pdfBlob],
  });

 // DriveApp.getFiles() // This comment line is used for automatically detecting a scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly". In order to export PDF data, I thought that this scope might be required to be included.
}
```

- When this script is run, the PDF data is retrieved from the cells "A1:I5" in "Sheet1", and an email is sent using the email address retrieved from "K2". The PDF is used as an attachment file.

#### References:

- [Example on how to export a Google sheet to various formats, includes most PDF options](https://gist.github.com/Spencer-Easton/78f9867a691e549c9c70)
- [sendEmail(message) of Class MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage)

Comment: That's what actually needed, great. Can we set margins for the PDF, is there any parameter possible?

Comment: @Asif Sheikh Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `Can we set margins for the PDF, is there any parameter possible?`, in this case, you can see the information at [Example on how to export a Google sheet to various formats, includes most PDF options](Example on how to export a Google sheet to various formats, includes most PDF options).