# Can I get Google slides' thumbnail url using Google App scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to get a thumbnail url of Google slides' page.
I checked that I can get a first page's thumbnail url by

`var file = DriveApp.getFileById('IdOfSlide')
var url = Drive.Files.get(file.getId()).thumbnailLink`

However I can not get a thumbnail url of a page in the middle of a slide, like page 10 or so.
Is there any way to get the thumbnail url of each page?

Comment: You can download the current the current slide from the file menu.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! However, I'd like to get a thumbnail's link through Google App Scripts, because I plan to throw the slide's thumbnail to the slack's bot.

Comment: I found a helpful answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662455/how-to-download-google-slides-as-images

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't know about that I think I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Link to any slide thumbnail:

`https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/<your_file_id>/export?format=png&pageid=<your_slide_id_as_g12341524615_2_0>`

You have either to be logged in as an owner, or at least to have a viewing access