# Google Suite - Apps Script - Download Slides as PNG files via API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

Good Morning All.  I have written a short script which batch-creates [single page] Google Slides based on rows from a spreadsheet.  While in the loop for each creation, I would like to create a PNG of the Slide in Google Drive (or download on the user's desktop).  These pictures should be the same specs as if a user clicked File>Download>PNG - the heavy small text requires full projector HD - so I don't believe I can use the "Thumbnail" function which appears limited to 1600 pixels.

My code below generates the error "Converting from text/html to image/png is not supported" - so I'm not sure if this is a limitation of the API or a problem with my coding.  Thank you in advance.

```
  var options =
     {
       "contentType" : "image/PNG"
     };
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/' + presentationCopyId + '/export/PNG';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var image = response.getAs(MimeType.PNG);
  image.setName(SlideName);
  DriveApp.createFile(image);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, It is possible.

You can use Google slide API and make a PNG file of every page of Google slide.

Here is the code,
**BUT first you have to enable API as following**

1. open script editor
2. click on  resources-> Advanced Google Services
3. Enable Google slide API and Drive API .
4. click on ok

now copy and paste this code,
and write your slide ID in presentationID.

```
function generateScreenshots() {
  
  var presentationId = "***ADD YOUR Google Slide ID Only***";
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId);
  var baseUrl =
    "https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations/{presentationId}/pages/{pageObjectId}/thumbnail";
  var parameters = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
    contentType: "application/json",
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  // Log URL of the main thumbnail of the deck
  Logger.log(Drive.Files.get(presentationId).thumbnailLink);

  // For storing the screenshot image URLs
  var screenshots = [];

  var slides = presentation.getSlides().forEach(function(slide, index) {
    var url = baseUrl
      .replace("{presentationId}", presentationId)
      .replace("{pageObjectId}", slide.getObjectId());
    var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, parameters));

    // Upload Googel Slide image to Google Drive
    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(response.contentUrl).getBlob();
    DriveApp.createFile(blob).setName("Image " + (index + 1) + ".png");

    screenshots.push(response.contentUrl);
  });

  return screenshots;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes - it seems like google has added in the support for PNGs. Great news for all of us. Appreciate you diving in there.

Comment: Great answer! Glad to see this looked at again.

Comment: you don't need Drive API

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it returned HTML instead of PNG is because you need to have access to presentation for this link to work.
So either make it 'Anyone with this link can view', or use login credentials as parameters in your request:

```
function test() {
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/<your_file_id>/export?format=png&pageid=<your_slide_id_as_g1234153524615_2_0>';
  var parameters = {
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }
  };
  var imageblob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, parameters).getBlob();
  DriveApp.createFile(imageblob);  
}
```

You don't need either Drive API or Slides API for this.

If someone knows how to define the image size/resolution in the request let me know.

Answer (score -1):

***This answer is outdated, leaving up for documentation purposes but please see [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63850712/11551468).***

---

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately it is not possible to export a Slides as a PNG file using the the Slides nor Drive APIs.*

#### More Information:

[According to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-export-formats), there are only four available MimeTypes for exporting Presentations files:

- `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation`
- `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation`
- `application/pdf`
- `text/plain`

Attempting to export to the `image/png` MIME Type results in the following error:

> Converting from text/html to image/png is not supported

For testing purposes, I tried using the `/export/pdf` endpoint and making a second conversion to `PNG` from there like so:

```js
function slidesAsPngAttempt() {
  var presentationCopyId = "1Loa...pQs";  
  var options =
      {
        "contentType" : "application/pdf"
      };
  // for exporting to pdf the /export/pdf needs to be all lower case to avoid 404
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/' + presentationCopyId + '/export/pdf';  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var pdfAsblob = response.getBlob();
 
  var image = pdfAsblob.getAs('image/png');
  
  image.setName(DriveApp.getFileById(presentationCopyId).getName());
  DriveApp.createFile(image);  
}
```

Unfortunately, a similar error occurs when running `var image = pdfAsblob.getAs('image/png')`:

> Converting from application/pdf to image/png is not supported.

From the same export MIME types reference documentation, the only export types available for `PDF` files are:

- `text/csv`
- `text/tab-separated-values`
- `application/zip`

#### References:

- [G Suite documents and corresponding export MIME types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-export-formats)
- [Google Apps Script - method `Blob.getAs(contentType)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getascontenttype)

Comment: Appreciate it, I feared this may be the case.  A PDF may actually work for my process.  However, modifying the code above left me with a PDF of "One account. All of google. Sign in to Continue."  Duplicated Slide has its permission set to a view link (shared).  Is there another authentication/setting I should be calling?