# Error converting google slide to image using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-slides-api

This is the code I am using to convert my google slide to image:

```
function myFunction() {
  var dApp = DriveApp;
  var folder = dApp.getFoldersByName("til");
  
  var til = folder.next();
  var filesIter = til.getFiles();
  var i = 0;
  while(filesIter.hasNext() && i < 50){
    var file = filesIter.next();
    Logger.log(file.getId());
    
    exportSlideImages(file.getId(), file.getName())
    break;
    i = i + 1;
  }
  
}

function exportSlideImages(presentationId, imageName) {
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId);
  var baseUrl =
    "https://slides.googleapis.com/v1/presentations/{presentationId}/pages/{pageObjectId}/thumbnail";
  var parameters = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
    contentType: "application/json",
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  
  presentation.getSlides().forEach(function(slide, i) {
    var url = baseUrl
      .replace("{presentationId}", presentationId)
      .replace("{pageObjectId}", slide.getObjectId());
    
    var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, parameters));
    Logger.log(response)
    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(response.contentUrl).getBlob();
    blob.setName(imageName +'.png');
    DriveApp.createFile(blob);
   
    
  });
}
```

It did create an image file but I got this output in the file:

> "code": 403,
> "message": "Google Slides API has not been used in project 396798675804 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting
> (a link was given here to)
> then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
> the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",

But what I don't understand is I don't have any project with id 396798675804. What am I doing wrong?? Any pointers??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable the Google Slides Advanced service because your code is using UrlFetchApp to call the Slides API

Related

- [403 error with message "Google Slides API has not been used in project ... before or it is disabled"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41367365/1595451)
- [Google Suite - Apps Script - Download Slides as PNG files via API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59845753/1595451)